# If a sequence is unbounded from above, it has a subsequence with $x_{n_k} > k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an unbounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. If $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is unbounded above, show that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ has a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ with $x_{n_k} > k$ for all $k$ in $\mathbb{N}$.

I do not know how to start at this problem. Should I start by using the definition of a subsequence diverging to $+\infty$ (for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ , there exists $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_n > M$)? After all, the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is stated to be "unbounded above".

Should I use the fact that if $(x_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a subsequence of $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, then $n_k > k$ for every $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

A sequence $(x_n)$ is "bounded above" if there is a number $M$ such that $x_n\le M$ for all $n$. If the sequence is "unbounded above", that means there is **no such $M$**; in other words, for **any** number $M$, it is **not true** that $x_n\le M$ for all $n$; in other words, for any number $M$, there is some $n$ such that $x_n\gt M$.

Answer (score 1):

Choose arbitrary $n_{k_1}>1$ (which exists since $x_n$ unbounded from above implies the existence of a subsequence $x_{n(h)}\to +\infty$).
Choose $x_{n_{k+1}}>k+1$ from $\{x_n\}\backslash \{x_{n_1},\cdots,x_{n_{k}} \}$. This is possible since 
$$\sup_h x_{n(h)} \backslash\{x_{n_1},\cdots,x_{n_{k}} \}= \sup_h x_{n(h)}= +\infty.$$